# qtcreator examples not enabled

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I installed qtcreator on a Ubuntu 11.10

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

the versions installed are:  QT Creator 2.2.1, QT 4.7.3

When i start qtcreator, to explore QT C++ examples the button is greyed out/disabled and it says Examples not installed.

Neither does qtdemo show any demo/documentation?

Do i have to install examples, doc  separately? If yes, how?

How can i enable examples in qtcreator and documentation in qtdemo?

**EDIT:
In response to one answer below from @Murtuza Kabul, I tried many things to point qtcreator to correct qt but could not. So  I did uninstall qtcreator and qt-sdk and reinstalled qt-sdk. So now qtcreator is what comes with qt-sdk . It still says examples not installed.**

Comment: How was qt libraries installed??

Comment: @UmNyobe - qtlibraries were installed as apt-get install libqt4-dev libqt4-core

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded `Qt 5.1` directly from [qt-project.org](https://qt-project.org/downloads) and installed as admin (with sudo) on Linux Mint 12 (based on Ubuntu).

If I started `qtcreator` as normal user I didn't have examples but if started `qtcreator` as admin (with sudo) I had all examples.

My problem was with `examples` folder privilages. It was the only folder without `read/execute` privilage for all users (`/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc/examples`). All other folders inside (and outside) `examples` had privilages for all users.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say - as [HostileFork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211160/hostilefork) mentioned in comment - `sudo chown -R +rx /opt/Qt/5.1.0/gcc/examples` was solution to this problem.

**EDIT:**

As noted by Climax - it should be `chmod` instead of `chown`

`sudo chmod -R +rx /opt/Qt/5.1.0/gcc/examples`

Comment: For me with 5.1.1 in Kubuntu, this fixed it: `sudo chown -R +rx /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc/examples` .  IIRC this problem has been around a while if you install as admin, but then there were other problems you'd have if you didn't.  :-/

Comment: You are right. `sudo chown ...` is solution to this problem - I didn't mention it in answer.

Comment: You are right. Last edit was made long time after entry and I didn't pay attention that I copy line with mistake.

Comment: didn't work for me, qtcreator finds the folder but shows no example.

Answer (score 1):

[image]You also need to install qtsdk. It comes with the examples and binaries required to run the qt project. If you install the sdk, it will provide you an interface to update the sdk and install/uninstall different parts of the sdk whereby you will be able to choose if you want to install the examples or not

Comment: on Ubuntu can qtsdk be installed using the apt package manager?

Comment: try out this sudo apt-get install qt-sdk

Comment: Did install apt-get install qt-sdk. It did install sdk, but still qtcreator shows no examples. During sdk installation, it did not offer any interface to select examples etc. Don't know if a reboot is needed:)

Comment: go to sdk maintenance tool, it will give you access to different components

Comment: As you have installed qtcreator yourself (not as a part of qt sdk), you will have to make it auto detect insalled version of qt and when you do so, it will also detect the examples directory.

Comment: go to preferences > build and run > qt versions and let qt creator detect installed sources and binaries. It will automatically locate the examples directory also.

Comment: Thanks. So how do i do that? Do u mean I need to add some path in qtcreator --> Tools -->options : There i see something to effect of Auto-detected...

Comment: I don't have any menu saying "preferences" in first place? I have Tools

Comment: I'm using mac so it might be somewhat different but you can see from the screenshot I have given here

Comment: I even uninstalled qtcreator and qt-sdk and reinstalled qt-sdk. Still no luck

Comment: Well, I believe it is somewhere has to do with paths. Somehow qtcreator is unable to find the path of examples and hence it is not working well. However, I'm not much familiar with linux so cannot give you exact solution but suggest a clue to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install the qt4-demos package.

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-demos
```

I found the sample code installed in `/usr/lib/qt4/demos/`. Also the qtdemo program was installed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qtdemo`.

It seems only a limited set of examples are installed by this package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 7.
How I solved this:

- I open QT Creator.
- I select menu-option [Tools]
- From there I select [Options...]
- From there I select the [Kits] option on the left-hand side
- I select the tab [QT Versions]
- I click The [Add...] button: to add the QT version that I am using...
  ... I am presented with a windows-explorer screen to select something...
  ... I go to the main directory on which QT is installed (in my case: C:\Qt)...
  ... In the explorer "Search" I enter **qmake** (without the quotes)...
  ... There is a single **qmake** EXECUTABLE file displayed - I double-click it!...
  ... I press [Apply], then [OK].

Walla - it works! I now have examples!